# Trigger Powershell Command to Copy SQL Backups to Network Drive

Tags: backup, sql-server-2008, powershell

I've got two servers on a workgroup and I need to transfer my SQL Server 2008 Backups from the local drive of one to a network drive on another. Ideally, I'd like to have SQL call the Powershell script after it does the backup. Anyone have a script that does this? Is there a better way?

I tried to have SQL Backup straight to the network drive but it doesn't seem I can do that without them being on the same domain.

Answer (score 2):

Powershell can certainly do that, but I find ROBOCOPY easier, just use the /MIR option to automatically purge older ones after creating a Maintenance cleanup plan on the SQL server to keep get rid of backups more than X days, and you'll always have copies on the netowrk drive;

You can set up the copy as a Windows Scheduled Task, or as a SQL Agent task via an Operating System command.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this script for myself. It creates backup right into network share with my own comfortable file name formatting. It executes from windows scheduler.

```
function Backup-Database {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        $Server,
        [String[]]$Database,
        [String]$Path,
        [Switch]$CreateSubfolder,
        [Switch]$Check,
        [Switch]$CopyOnly,
        [Switch]$BackupDatabase = $true,
        [Switch]$BackupTransactionLog,
        [Switch]$NoInnerVerbose,
        [Switch]$Differential
    )

    begin {
        $AllDatabases = @()
    }
    process {
        #All database names into 1 list
        $AllDatabases += $Database
    }
    end {
        $DefaultProgressPreference = $ProgressPreference
        if (-not $Path.EndsWith('\')) {
            $Path = $Path + '\'
        }
        #$Differential = $false
        $RetainDays = 0
        if ($Differential) {
            $RetainDays = 31
        }
        if ($NoInnerVerbose) {
            $Verbose = $false
        }
        else {
            $Verbose = ($VerbosePreference -eq 'Continue')
        }

        Import-Module SQLPS -Verbose:$false -WarningAction SilentlyContinue
        $Activity = "Backing up databases"

        # Some cmdlets cannot specify timeouts, this is workout
        Write-Verbose "Connecting to $Server"
        Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -CurrentOperation "Connecting to $Server"
        $ServerInstance = New-Object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $Server
        $ServerInstance.ConnectionContext.StatementTimeout = 0

        for ($index = 0; $index -lt $AllDatabases.Count; $index++) {
            $TotalProgress = $index / $AllDatabases.Count * 100
            $DB = $AllDatabases[$index]
            $DBTitle = [Char]::ToUpperInvariant($DB[0]) + $DB.Substring(1)
            $Operation = "Backing up $DBTitle database"
            #Write-Verbose $Operation

            if ($Check) {
                Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -CurrentOperation $Operation -Status 'Checking database integrity' -PercentComplete $TotalProgress
                Write-Verbose "Checking $DB database integrity"
                Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Database $DB -Query 'DBCC CHECKDB($(dbname))' -Variable "dbname='$DB'" -Verbose:$Verbose -QueryTimeout 65535
            }

            if ($BackupTransactionLog) {
                Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -CurrentOperation $Operation -Status 'Backing up transaction log' -PercentComplete $TotalProgress
                $FileName = $Path
                if ($CreateSubfolder) {
                    $FileName = Join-Path $FileName $DBTitle
                    if (-not (Test-Path $FileName)) {
                        Push-Location
                        New-Item $FileName -ItemType Container -Force | Out-Null
                        Pop-Location
                    }
                }
                $FileName = Join-Path $FileName "$($DBTitle)_$(Get-Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm')_log.trn"

                Write-Verbose "Backing up transaction log to $FileName"
                $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
                Backup-SqlDatabase -Database $DB -BackupFile $FileName -InputObject $ServerInstance -BackupAction Log -Checksum:$Check -CompressionOption On -CopyOnly:$CopyOnly -RetainDays $RetainDays -LogTruncationType Truncate -Verbose:$Verbose
                $ProgressPreference = $DefaultProgressPreference

                if ($Check) {
                    Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -CurrentOperation $Operation -Status 'Checking transaction log backup integrity' -PercentComplete $TotalProgress
                    $FileNumber = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Query 'select position from msdb..backupset where database_name=$(dbname) and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=$(dbname))' -Variable "dbname='$DB'" -Verbose:$Verbose | select -ExpandProperty position
                    $Position = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Query 'RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK=$(filename)' -Variable "filename='$FileName'" -Verbose:$Verbose | select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Position
                    if ($FileNumber -ne $null -and $FileNumber -eq $Position) {
                        Write-Verbose "Verifying backup file '$FileName', position $FileNumber"
                        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Query 'RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK=$(filename) WITH FILE=$(position)' -Variable "filename='$FileName'","position=$FileNumber" -QueryTimeout 65535 -Verbose:$Verbose
                    }
                    else {
                        Write-Error "Transaction log verify failed. Backup information for database $DB not found or incorrect (query position $FileNumber, file position $Position)" -Category InvalidResult
                    }
                }
            }

            if ($BackupDatabase) {
                Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -CurrentOperation $Operation -Status 'Backing up database' -PercentComplete $TotalProgress
                $FileName = $Path
                if ($CreateSubfolder) {
                    $FileName = Join-Path $FileName $DBTitle
                    if (-not (Test-Path $FileName)) {
                        Push-Location
                        New-Item $FileName -ItemType Container -Force | Out-Null
                        Pop-Location
                    }
                }
                if ($Differential) {
                    $part = 'diff'
                }
                else {
                    $part = 'full'
                }
                $FileName = Join-Path $FileName "$($DBTitle)_$(Get-Date -format 'yyyy-MM-dd_HH-mm')_$part.bak"

                Write-Verbose "Backing up $DB database to $FileName"
                $ProgressPreference = 'SilentlyContinue'
                Backup-SqlDatabase -Database $DB -BackupFile $FileName -InputObject $ServerInstance -BackupAction Database -Checksum:$Check -CompressionOption On -Incremental:$Differential -CopyOnly:$CopyOnly -RetainDays $RetainDays -Verbose:$Verbose
                $ProgressPreference = $DefaultProgressPreference
                #Backing up (Database: 'accounting' ; Server: 'Serv1C' ; Action = 'Database') .

                if ($Check) {
                    Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -CurrentOperation $Operation -Status 'Checking database backup integrity' -PercentComplete $TotalProgress
                    $FileNumber = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Query 'select position from msdb..backupset where database_name=$(dbname) and backup_set_id=(select max(backup_set_id) from msdb..backupset where database_name=$(dbname))' -Variable "dbname='$DB'" -Verbose:$Verbose | select -ExpandProperty position
                    $Position = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Query 'RESTORE HEADERONLY FROM DISK=$(filename)' -Variable "filename='$FileName'" -Verbose:$Verbose | select -Last 1 -ExpandProperty Position
                    if ($FileNumber -ne $null -and $FileNumber -eq $Position) {
                        Write-Verbose "Verifying backup file '$FileName', position $FileNumber"
                        Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $ServerInstance -Query 'RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK=$(filename) WITH FILE=$(position)' -Variable "filename='$FileName'","position=$FileNumber" -QueryTimeout 65535 -Verbose:$Verbose
                    }
                    else {
                        Write-Error "Database backup verify failed. Backup information for database $DB not found or incorrect (query position $FileNumber, file position $Position)" -Category InvalidResult
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        Write-Progress -Activity $Activity -Completed
    }
}

$Server = 'Serv1C'
$Databases = 'accounting3','zup','accounting','pult','accounting_ip','accounting_u','accounting_u2'
$Differential = $true
$TransactionLog = $true
$Check = $false
$BackupPath = '\\MAIN\Backup\SQL'
Backup-Database -Server $Server -Database $Databases -Path $BackupPath -CreateSubfolder -Verbose -NoInnerVerbose -Differential:$Differential -BackupTransactionLog:$TransactionLog -Check:$Check
```

Answer (score 0):

I use Powershell to invoke [RichCopy](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/2009.04.utilityspotlight.aspx). If you break your big files up into multiple chunks with a RAR utility, RichCopy can really haul bits.

Another approach is to use the PowerShell v2 BITS module, although I've not tried it yet.  Start with "import-module filetransfer" and "get-help add-filetransfer –example"

As for SQL calling the script, try having it call everything explicitly:

%windir%\system32\windowspowershell\v1.0\powershell.exe -nologo -command "&{C:\path\to\Script.ps1}"